# compare date trimming

Tags: php

I have a field (nonTimeStampDate) that has date like this

```
2010-03-15
```

and I want to check it against another field (timeStampDate) which is

```
2010-03-15 15:07:45
```

to see if the date matchs. But as you can see since the format is different it doesnt match even though the date is same.
Any help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: are you getting those values from a database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought is using `date()` and `strtotime()` to reformat them.

```
$date1 ="2010-03-15";
$date2 = "2010-03-15 15:07:45";

if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1)) == date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2)))
{ 
   //do something 
}
```

This would work and give you more flexibility in how the two dates formatted to begin with. Not the most elegant.

Comment: problem is that I am comparing it in sql so $date2  is a field value in table

Comment: If you are doing this from sql, try using DATE_FORMAT:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Field1,  '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(Field2, '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: @kmfk @Autolycus `SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(Field1) = DATE(Field2)` would be faster

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try this code:

```
if (strpos($date1, $date2) !== false)  {
  // Your code here
}
```

It is a bit faster than exploding the value by a space as suggested by Anax. Make sure that $date2 contains the shorter of the two dates.

Answer (score 3):

If you are certain about the input string format, you need to split it and take the first part, in order to compare it with your original date:

```
$splits = explode(' ', $original);
$datapart = $splits[0];
if ($datepart == $nonTimeStampDate) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What Anax says, or if these values are in MySQL tables, you can use MySQLs datetime functions (like DATE()) to compare them in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Then, just compare the date part:

```
<?php

if( substr('2010-03-15 15:07:45', 0, 10) == '2010-03-15' ){
    echo 'Dates match';
}

?>
```

Whatever, if you need to do serious date handling, you need to use a proper format, such as a `DateTime` object.

Comment: like this different approach :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$firstDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2010-03-15"));
$secondDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2010-03-15 15:07:45"));     

if( $firstDate == $secondDate ) {
       // true    
}
```

Comment: problem is that I am comparing it in sql so $secondDate is a field value in table

Comment: Then you can get $secondDate from database directly before comparing it with $firstDate in if condition.